# Add a 1 if user entered an "*", or add a 0 if user entered a " " to an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, char, int

I need to take the users input (asterisk or a space) and if the user entered an asterisk I would then insert a 1 into an array, if the user entered a space I would then insert a 0 into an array. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void userInput(){
    printf("Enter Generation 0 (Length must be 10, * for 1 and " " for 0):\n");
    char c;                 /* int */
    int count;
    char arr[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if(c == '*')
            arr[i] = '1';
        else
            arr[i] = '0';
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%c", arr[j]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    userInput();
}
```

The problem is that the loop only allows the user to enter a character 6 times and then prints.

Output if I enter all *'s:

```
Enter Generation 0 (Length must be 10, * for 1 and  for 0):
*
*
*
*
*
1010101010
```

Output if I enter all spaces:

```
Enter Generation 0 (Length must be 80, * for 1 and  for 0):





0000000000
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", &c);` --> `scanf(" %c", &c);` notice the added space, to prevent the previous `newline` from begin read.

Comment: As an alternative to Weather Vane's suggestion, make sure that the entered character is either an asterisk or a space before adding to the array. (That may involve turning the for loop to a while, where you advance `i` only when you append to the string.)

Comment: If you're on ascii, you can write `'0' + ((c >> 1)&1)` to the array unconditionally.

Comment: Actually my commented fix will fail, because the `space` will be skipped too! Pick a different character from `space` perhaps the period `'.'`.

Comment: That worked, however it doesn't track when I enter a space. Anyway I can track spaces?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything other then a space.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use anything other then a space." But you haven't even used a space in the code.

Comment: The "else
            arr[i] = '0';" is if the user enters a space

Comment: Try `if(c == '*')
            arr[i] = '1';
        else if(c == ' ')
            arr[i] = '0'; else if(c == '\n') i--; else { fprintf(stderr, "Invalid character '%c'; Try again\n", c); i--; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are any number of ways to approach capturing the `'*'` and `' '` and translating them to `1` and `0`, respectively. You are essentially writing a little input handler that will read until your array is full, or the user terminates input with <kbd>[ctrl + d]</kbd>. You simply need to check to insure the array is not full and that you haven't reached `EOF`. Something simple will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 10

int main (void) {

    unsigned char arr[MAXC] = {0};
    int c = 0, i, idx = 0;

    while (idx < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '*') arr[idx++] = 1u;
        if (c == ' ') arr[idx++] = 0u;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf (" arr[%d] : %u\n", i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

It will take any form of input, act appropriately for `'*'` and `' '`, and ignore an additional characters until the array is full or `EOF` is generated:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdspcasterix
(**) (**)
  (**)
*
 arr[0] : 1
 arr[1] : 1
 arr[2] : 0
 arr[3] : 1
 arr[4] : 1
 arr[5] : 0
 arr[6] : 0
 arr[7] : 1
 arr[8] : 1
 arr[9] : 1

$ ./bin/rdspcasterix
The quick*brown fox*jumps over*a lazy*dog
**  **
 arr[0] : 0
 arr[1] : 1
 arr[2] : 0
 arr[3] : 1
 arr[4] : 0
 arr[5] : 1
 arr[6] : 0
 arr[7] : 1
 arr[8] : 1
 arr[9] : 1
```

There is no one-right way to do this, so take a look at all answers and choose the one that works best for your situation.

Comment: You should check for `EOF` in the inner loop's condition. newline is already ignored by the filters like any other character.

Comment: Ehm, You can remove the explit check for newline. Why should that be treated different from e.g. `'A'`? Just `while ( (idx ...) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) ) { ...`

Comment: Chuckling... damn you are right on both counts. I guess I'm just partial to the newline... You only need a single loop...

Comment: Yes, now it is better than mine. I just concentrated too much on giving hints so OP could finish her homework himself. But from the comment she seems not be that far already.

Comment: This code worked, thank you so much. I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use fgetc with STDIN as your file stream to read char by char

***EDIT*** Added a solution with buffer validation

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define EXTRACHARS 2
#define SIZE 10

static void clear_buf(void)
{
  int ch;
  while(ch = getc(stdin), ch != '\n' && ch!=EOF);
  clearerr(stdin);
}
int main(void)
{
  int c = 0; 
  char seq[SIZE + EXTRACHARS];

  printf("Enter 10 * or ' ': ");  
  fgets(seq, SIZE+EXTRACHARS, stdin);
  if (seq[strlen(seq)- 1] != '\n')
    {
      printf("Buffer overflowed \n");
      clear_buf();
    }
  else
    {
      while(c < SIZE)
    {
      if(seq[c] == '*')
        {
          printf("1");
        }
      else if(seq[c] == ' ')
        {
          printf("0");
        }
      ++c;
    }
      printf("\n");
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Added a solution that uses buffer safety

Answer (score 0):

ok new code work real well for me tested on QT Ide Mingw Compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void userInput(){
    printf("Enter Generation 0 (Length must be 10, * for 1 and " " for 0):\n");
    char c;
    char temp;
    char arr[10];
    int i=0;
    do{
        printf("\nEnter number %d : ", i+1);
        c = getchar();
        while((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);    // this is alternative to fflush
        if(c == 42)     // 42 is ascii code to *
            arr[i] = '1';
        else
            arr[i] = '0';

        i++;
    }while((c!=EOF)&&(i<10));
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        printf("%c\n", arr[j]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    userInput();
}
```

this may not work on online compilers

Comment: I think `if(c == '*')` will be better

Comment: ok i'll be nice as per as user comfort use    42     or     '*'     ty for comment :)

Comment: This program has the same problem as the OP's.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int` on purpose. And this is no way better than OPs.

Comment: "// this is alternative to fflush" - What? Haow is that related to fflush? Does it also invoke UB?

Comment: No this does not invoke UB it just reads to EOF or end of line, using fflush will resets POSIX and dump all the data so reading until \n or EOF is better option

Comment: I know that this is not good way to get input but i try to keep my answer as near possible to question